# Elements in commutative diagram

Tags: notation, category-theory

The same way I define a function, by explicitly including the image of an element:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{R} & & \overset{\exp}{\longrightarrow} & & \mathbb{R} \\
x  & & \longrightarrow & & e^x \\
\end{aligned}
$$
I think a commutative diagram would be clearer if I include explicit symbols for elements, e.g. starting from:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\frak{g} @>\exp>> {\mathcal G} \\
@V\mathcal{T} V V @VV\mathcal{T} V\\
T_X \frak{g} @>>Dexp> T_{e^X} {\mathcal G}
\end{CD}
$$
then I could write an additional parallel diagram with the elements:
$$
\begin{CD}
X @>\exp>> e^X \\
@V\mathcal{T} V V @VV\mathcal{T} V\\
Y @>>Dexp> D_X Y
\end{CD}
$$
Do you think this is correct and usual notation? I do not like that $\mathcal{T}$ is not a function, i.e. one could read $Y=\mathcal{T}(X)$ that makes no sense. I could also include elements in the same diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
X \in \frak{g} @>\exp>> {\mathcal G} \ni e^X\\
@V\mathcal{T} V V @VV\mathcal{T} V\\
Y \in T_X \frak{g} @>>Dexp> T_{e^X} {\mathcal G} \ni D_X Y
\end{CD}
$$
And suppose I want to add a third column of vertical arrows... maybe a bit muddled?

Is there a more or less canonical or accepted away to write this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this kind of notation is general. Especially on blackboard we can denote elements of the sets for a concrete category just beside the object, with other color, smaller.

By the way, to differentiate between denoting the domain and codomain of a function $f:A\to B$, for the assignments we were taught to rather use symbol $a\mapsto b$.